# pylint code repository plugin: do not fail CI checks

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

We would like to gradually improve our code quality in foundry code repositories. As a start we would like to run pylint in every CI run, but do not fail the run, just get a pylint score in the logs.

How can we configure the 'com.palantir.conda.pylint'-plugin to return exit code 0 and not fail and to show us the pylint output in each CI run?

Comment: I don't think this is possible just fyi, I'll take a look either way though

Comment: I was hoping to leverage pylintrc file for that but couldn't find a solution. btw. the foundry sample Python transforms repo fails pylint checks - so it's really not a nice experience for a "unexperienced" developer to start with failing Checks.

Comment: hehe it's partially on purpose, to provide folks a sense of a pipeline in the wild. I'm actually planning to do a youtube video to review that code, but haven't had the time

Comment: Can we get a solution for this? We are going to pass this feature request through our usual channels as well.